# Is there a way to set more than one property in a single @Input() set-?

Tags: angular, typescript

So, I'm working on an component that sets two different properties in order to conduct a query, looking something like this:

```
  @Input() set stringValue(_stringValue: any) {
    this._stringValue = _stringValue;
    this.launchMyQuery()
  }

  @Input() set idValue(_idValue: any) {
    this._idValue = _idValue;
    // This value is optional so I chose not to launch the query here
  }
```

I've been trying to set both properties (stringvalue and idValue) within the same `Input() set` method so that I can launch the query after setting both parameters and thus avoiding to condition the query under only one of the methods. Is there a way to do this? Something like

```
@Input set (value1: any, value2: any) {
// Code goes here. Needless to say, this did not work
}
```

Comment: y dont u pass an object containing these values? ```{ stringValue: "whatever string", idValue: "whatever id" }``` And use this as a single ```@input() values: YourType;```

Comment: Hi JurgenBlitz if  my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 

Comment: Hi malbarmawi, you are correct- sorry for not taking this into consideration. The solution did not fully work, but I believe it was more due to my project's variables being labeled as private and due to parts of the HTML wanting to access the parameters individually. The destructuring of the parameters themselves worked well during compilation, and I also wanted to thank you for the link you shared. Marking it as solved, and thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way by create a property that accept an `array` or an `object` as parameter

**parameter as an array**

```
@Input() set data(values) { 
 const [stringValue, idValue] = values; 
 this.stringValue = stringValue;
 this.idValue  = idValue;
 this.launchMyQuery();
}
```

or this way

```
@Input() set data([stringValue, idValue]) { 
 this.stringValue = stringValue;
 this.idValue  = idValue;
 this.launchMyQuery()
}
```

**parameter as an object**

```
@Input() set data({stringValue, idValue}) { 
 this.stringValue = stringValue;
 this.idValue  = idValue;
 this.launchMyQuery()
}
```

check this  [**A Dead Simple intro to Destructuring JavaScript Objects**](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/)